# C# - xml to listview in winforms

Tags: xml, listview

you can help with writing code for parsing xml of this type in the listview in winformsl. You should get the name of the color and its value. Do not judge the costly newcomer in this case. Thanks in advance for the advice.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <resources>
          <color name="abc_input_method_navigation_guard">@android:color/black</color>
          <color name="abc_search_url_text_normal">#ff7fa87f</color>
          <color name="abc_search_url_text_pressed">@android:color/black</color>
          <color name="abc_search_url_text_selected">@android:color/black</color>
          <color name="accent_material_dark">@color/material_deep_teal_200</color>
          <color name="accent_material_light">@color/material_deep_teal_500</color>
          <color name="background_floating_material_dark">@color/material_grey_800</color>
          <color name="background_floating_material_light">@android:color/white</color>
          <color name="background_material_dark">@color/material_grey_850</color>
          <color name="background_material_light">@color/material_grey_50</color>
          <color name="bright_foreground_disabled_material_dark">#80ffffff</color>
          <color name="bright_foreground_disabled_material_light">#80000001</color>
    </resources>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PFB code. It is working.

```
   XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load("yourXMLFile.xml");
   var list = xmlDoc.Root.Elements("color")
                       .Select(element => element.Value)
                       .ToList();
```